# Class including list

Tags: c#, list, class, object, properties

when i am assigning the values in the list its saying object not set to instance of an object any help , i can retrieve from other service , when i am trying to assign the value in the list its creating problem

```
public class exam
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string RollNo { get; set; }

    public List<Subject> subject{get; set;}
 }


 public class Subject
 {
    public string SubjectName{ get; set;}
    public string SubjectPartNo{ get; set; }        
 }


 exam ex = new exam()

 ex.Name = "john"
 ex.Age = 22
 ex.RollNo = 13
 ex.subject.SubjectName = "English"
 ex.subject.SubjectPartNo = 1
```

Comment: You declare your `subject` property. But you never instantiate it. Change the declaration to `List<Subject> subject{get; set;} = new List<Subject>();`. Oh wait, you can't do this: `ex.subject.SubjectName = "English"`; the `subject` property is a list. You need to create a new `Subject` and add it to the list

Comment: I declare new list List<subject> sub = new List<subject>() and  sub .Add(new subject() { SubjectName= "English", SubjectPartNo = "tow" }); then i want to attached to class ex.subject = sub , here is the problem

Answer (score 0):

`subject` is an object which is defined as a list of type `Subject`.  Like every other object this needs to first be instantiated before it can be used.  The fact that it is inside `Exam` (another object) doesn't change this.

So you can do this either during property assignment like this.

```
public List<Subject> subject { get; set; } = new List<Subject>();
```

or you can create a constructor and instantiate it there

```
public exam()
{
    subject = new List<Subject>();
}
```

So now you have an empty list, that's the first part of the problem resolved.  But you are still trying to assign values to it incorrectly.

`subject` is a list of `Subject`, so this means we can only add `Subject` objects to it.

First create a new Subject object and add values to it. (can also be done inline).  Here we create two;

```
Subject sub1 = new Subject();
sub1.SubjectName = "English";
sub1.SubjectPartNo = "1";

Subject sub2 = new Subject();
sub2.SubjectName = "Maths";
sub2.SubjectPartNo = "2";
```

Then add these to your list;

```
exam  ex = new exam();

ex.Name = "john"
ex.Age = "22";
ex.RollNo = "13";
ex.subject.Add(sub1);
ex.subject.Add(sub2);
```

Now you have an `exam` object with 2 `Subjects`

BTW:  You have many properties, such as age, which are defined as string but you are trying to add integer values to them.  They need to be correctly defined according to the right datatype.  Don't just set everything to string because it is "easier" now, it will cause you problems later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Is there any other way to do this i have to user for loop to add subjects its like 2 or 4 or 10